# how to share a memory mapped file with a structure containing a time_t type created using a c++ program with c# program?

Tags: c#, c++, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

Using memory mapped files I want to share a structure between c++ and c# process.

structure in C++

```
typedef struct Conn
{
    int num;
    time_t  ReqTime;    
}
```

structure in c#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct Conn
{
        public int num;
        public DateTime ReqTime;
};
```

Trial 1:
This code prints some random Datetime values.

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MapFile"))
            {
                using (var accessor = memMapFile.CreateViewAccessor())
                {
                    Conn data;
                    accessor.Read<Conn>(0, out  data);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.num);
                    DateTime ReqTime;
                        unsafe
                        {
                            ReqTime = data.ReqTime;

                        }

                    Console.WriteLine(ReqTime);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Trial 2: 
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct Conn
{
        public int num;
        public long ReqTime;
};
```

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var memMapFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MapFile"))
            {
                using (var accessor = memMapFile.CreateViewAccessor())
                {
                    Conn data;
                    accessor.Read<Conn>(0, out  data);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.num);
                    long ReqTime;
                        unsafe
                        {
                            ReqTime = data.ReqTime;

                        }
                    DateTime dt = new System.DateTime(ReqTime);                 
                    Console.WriteLine(dt);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Trial 3: when I tried to use a byte array for ReqTime in structure, I found garbage values getting printed.

Can you please point out the mistakes I have done in implementation or suggest a better approach?
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: and `time_t` this is 32 or 64 bit ? `DateTime` this is what ? are equal to `time_t` ? how *c++* code fill memory ?

Comment: I'd recommend in C++ using types `int32_t` and `uint64_t` instead, you get guaranteed sizes this way. And I wouldn't count on C#'s `DateTime` being layout compatible with that. Better calculate explicitly (`DateTime` should provide a function for) seconds since epoque (if that's the time format you intend to use).

Comment: time_t is a 32-bit type.DateTime is a 64-bit type. Doesn't it get upgraded?

Comment: Not in this case. None of the two programmes can know about the other one how it would use the memory. So it is up to *you* to make sure both of them interprete the data in the memory the same way. It's quite similar if you let two different programmes communicate via a socket: *You* need to make sure that both programmes interprete the data the same way (e. g. both using little endian, size of data types, etc). There wouldn't even be a difference if you used C++ in both programmes. If you tell one to use a 32 bit and the other one a 64 bit data type, you'll get a mismatch...

Comment: Even worse: That can occur even inside one single programme: `void f(char* m) { *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(m) = 7ULL << 32; } void g(char const* m) { int32_t n = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t const*>(m); /* ... */ }` – the memory in question is just a bunch of bytes, by imposing a structure on you in the end do more or less the same as the casts in these two functions...

Comment: ```DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);                    
    DateTime date = epoch.AddMilliseconds(ReqTime);``` ReqTime long value : 6701112703701745664. Using epoche I am getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException.